# Cross-platform centralized desktop password manager

Tags: windows, linux, macos, passwords, password-management

I have been using [KeePass](http://keepass.info/) as a desktop password manager on Windows for many years. Love it! However, I am now needing to work on different platforms much of my day (Windows 7, Windows XP, Mac OS X, Ubuntu, and OpenSUSE.) I'm looking for a password manager I can share across all these platforms. My ideal solution would:

- Run natively (not in a virtual machine) on all platforms.
- Store the "official" copy of the password data on a local network so I can get to it from any and all machines. It is OK if it locks (or becomes read-only) when one client is accessing it.
- Keep a local cached copy (read-only is fine) so I can still get to my passwords when disconnected from the network.

Does any such beast exist?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.

KeePass has a cross-platform port called [KeePassX](http://www.keepassx.org/) which runs on Mac OS X and Linux. It uses the standard KeePass storage format, so it can be used interchangeably between KeePass and KeePassX. It is also included in the Ubuntu repositories by default.

For syncing the database between computers, you can use the cross-platform application [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/). Put your KeePass database in a Dropbox folder, and install Dropbox on each computer you want to access your KeePass database. Dropbox will keep a local copy on each computer, as well as an "official" copy on the server. You can then use KeePass/KeePassX to read/write to the file as normal, and it will be automatically synced between computers.

Comment: Perfect. Just what I was looking for. I rolled back to the 1.x version of Keepass, as that seems to be the most portable at this time. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I've kinda rolled my own with KeePass/KeePassX and rysync. I have my primary file on my laptop, which gets rsync'ed every few minutes to my server. Then I can rsync from the server to any other machine. I even have it so that I can access my file from my BlackBerry.

Comment: Yeah, KeepassX is cross platform. Cannot go wrong with that.